# ImportError; and zipimporters disappeared from pkgutil.iter_importers()

Tags: python, import, egg, python-import

I have a Django instance that's mysteriously incapable of import memcache ... after (some unknown event that happens after a period of running just fine.)

LAMP configuration:

- RHEL 5.7
- Apache 2.2.3
- mod_wsgi 2.3 (dynamically linked to Python2.5.4 .so)
- Python 2.5.4
- Django 1.2

memcache sits in: `/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/python_memcached-1.44-py2.5.ee/memcache.pyc`

If I open up a command shell, and `import memcache`, it imports just fine.

And for a time, in Django, `import memcache` works just fine.

But after some unknown event, the import fails: `ImportError: No module named memcache`

Just prior point of failure, I logged the system path, and the path explicitly includes `/usr/local/lib/python2.5` and `/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages`.

I also logged the response to `pkgutil.iter_importers()`, and found something interesting:  At the point of failure, iter_importers features NONE of the zipimporters -- and it is a zipimporter that is required to look inside the egg and find memcache.

If I manually import memcache, it functions:

```
try:
    import memcache
except ImportError:
    import zipimport
    zi = zipimport.zipimporter('/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/python_memcached-1.44-py2.5.egg')
    memcache = zi.load_module('memcache')
```

What is going on?  What can I do to make it work without the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  I found the answer.  There is [a bug](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/6467) in Python 2.5's os.listdir C implementation on 64-bit computers.  When I applied [the patch,](http://bugs.python.org/file10517/fix-unicode-listdir.patch) everything works permanently.